# Controlling XY Resolution on file geodatabase feature class output from Append?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, file-geodatabase, append

This question arises from research into [Appending polygon feature classes with already repaired geometry => WARNING 000442: self intersections from Check Geometry?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195920/appending-polygon-feature-classes-with-already-repaired-geometry-produces-feature)

Before running the code snippet below the properties of feature class rwc_aurukun show:

[image]

```
inputFileGDB = <file_geodatabase_where_all_work_is_done>
arcpy.env.workspace = inputFileGDB 
fcList = <list_of_feature_classes_including_"rwc_aurukun"_as_first_member>
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(inputFileGDB,"RWC","POLYGON",fcList[0])
coord_sys = arcpy.Describe(fcList[0]).spatialReference
arcpy.DefineProjection_management("RWC", coord_sys)
arcpy.env.XYDomain ="-180 -90 180 90"
arcpy.env.XYTolerance = "0.000000001 DecimalDegrees"
arcpy.Append_management(fcList,"RWC","NO_TEST")
```

After running the code snippet the properties of feature class RWC (which is 88 feature classes appended - including rwc_aurukun) show:

[image]

How can I control the XY Resolution on the output feature class (RWC)?

My experimentation with `arcpy.env.XYDomain` and `arcpy.env.XYTolerance` are not achieving the result that I am after.

Comment: Do you want to merge this with the original post, then steal my answer, or should  I repost?

Comment: The environment only applies if you go out of your way to use it over the preferred defaults.

Comment: @Vince I'm thinking that I'll make into duplicate, and probably merge, but initial testing has you getting me past both my questions but leaving one last thing that I'm still checking.

Comment: Are you interested in ArcObjects.. There are finer controls available there but aren't exposed to the desktop interface or arcpy.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I draw the line at ArcPy/Python coding but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [@Vince's answer to the earlier question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/195928/115) I am gaining some control.

My code now reads:

```
inputFileGDB = <file_geodatabase_where_all_work_is_done>
arcpy.env.workspace = inputFileGDB 
fcList = <list_of_feature_classes_including_"rwc_aurukun"_as_first_member>
sr = arcpy.Describe(fcList[0]).spatialReference
sr.setFalseOriginAndUnits(-400.0,-400.0,10000000.0) # from Vince
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(inputFileGDB,"RWC","POLYGON",fcList[0],"SAME_AS_TEMPLATE","SAME_AS_TEMPLATE",sr)
arcpy.Append_management(fcList,"RWC","NO_TEST")
```

and the properties of the RWC feature class are now:

[image]

The only glitch is that 25 self intersections still remain but these now seem tiny and after a Repair Geometry were gone.

```
Executing: CheckGeometry C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC_cg
Start Time: Fri Jun 03 12:35:37 2016
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 12986 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 16714 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 20151 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 26613 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 26629 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 29669 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 30888 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 32727 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 32867 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 33207 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 35415 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 38105 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 38197 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 39605 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 41180 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 41498 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 41501 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 43195 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 44768 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 45215 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 45644 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 46692 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 52702 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 53066 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
WARNING 000442: self intersections at 55112 in C:\Temp\DCDB\Staging.gdb\RWC
Succeeded at Fri Jun 03 12:40:28 2016 (Elapsed Time: 4 minutes 50 seconds)
```

Adding one more zero in the code above to make the line below resulted in the appended feature class having no geometry errors.

```
sr.setFalseOriginAndUnits(-400.0,-400.0,100000000.0)
```

Comment: You can go with a smaller resolution, but 1.1cm-sized intersections are likely to be noise

Comment: @Vince One more zero did the trick.

Comment: If it takes a 1.1mm resolution to prevent knots in GCS data, you may need to invest some time into a data quality review.