# Feature To Point for very small polygon in ArcGIS Desktop gives ERROR 000072: Cannot process feature?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

In ArcGIS 10.1, I'm trying to run Feature to Point for a polygon shapefile, selecting the box to generate points inside polygons. The process is failing with:

> ERROR 000072: Cannot process feature with OID 98720

The documentation suggests I run Repair Geometry, which I'd already done. I've checked the offending feature; it's very small, but has vertices. I can't see anything wrong with it.

Any idea what might be causing the error?

Comment: How big is 'very small'?

Comment: Did Repair Geometry say that there was anything that it could not repair?

Comment: Perhaps review http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195920/appending-polygon-feature-classes-with-already-repaired-geometry-warning-0004 It is NOT the same problem but may help suggest some things to think about when working with problematic geometries.

Comment: I'm not sure how to quantify how small it is, but it's a two-part sliver, with a total of 11 vertices.

Comment: Repair Geometry did not say there was anything it could not repair, and re-running it, it did not find any errors at all.

Comment: When I export the offending feature into its own shapefile and run Feature To Point on it, it works successfully. This leads me to believe I haven't correctly identified the problematic feature.

Comment: Try copying your problematic feature class to another using the Copy Features tool - perhaps it will leave some corruption behind, use a different grid size, or in some other way give you a feature class you can work with.

Comment: Try saving as .shp and also try saving to a geodatabase as a feature class

Comment: It turns out my question is incorrect. It is not a very small polygon, it is a polygon with 414 parts (and quite a lot of vertices). I'm fairly new here- should I close out the question and reask it correctly, edit the question, or simply continue to discuss here in the comments?

Comment: Since it currently has no answers I think that you should edit your question to make what you want to ask clear.

Comment: Since I asked this over two years ago, I no longer remember the details of this question. Should I delete the post?